# Regular expression for a facebook proxy email address

Tags: regex, facebook

What would be the regular expression to match a facebook proxy email address of a facebook user?

Comment: Any examples of a "facebook proxy email address"?

Comment: I did not have any examples that's why I asked this question. That page has an example. http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Roadmap_Email

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I figured it out.

```
/@proxymail\.facebook\.com/
```

matches a user's proxy email address on facebook.